# Laravel 5.6 - User not getting authenticated

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have looked for days, but my user never gets authenticated when using the auth middleware.

We don't use the standard laravel way, but using the standard auth middleware to block access to a route group. (in this example the dashboards)

The data is correct as it doesnt give any error message, but the user itself never gets authenticated. I've been stuck at it since wednesday and I hope any of you can finally fix this problem.

There isn't really any specific code, but my (try to) login user always get directed to the unauthenticated method. (which leads back to another route of mine, index)

Important database columns for login are called 'username' and 'password' (the standard name laravel uses)

So, please, if any of you can help, I'd be hella grateful!

**Inside LeerlingController (where login function is)**

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])){
        return redirect()->back()->with(['fail' => 'We konden je niet inloggen als '.$request->username]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('leerling.dashboard');
}
```

**Inside Leerling Model (the part to make it authenticatable)**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Leerling extends Model implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable {
use Authenticatable;
```

**Method that keeps happening while logging in a valid user as no fail message comes up**
Which is located in App\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
        ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
        : redirect()->route('index');
}
```

**The dashboard routes protected by auth middleware**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/leerling/dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'LeerlingController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'leerling.dashboard'
    ]);

    // Don't mind this one, it's for the admin dashboard
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'AdminController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'admin.dashboard'
    ]);
});
```

**Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Leerling::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Can you try `dd($exception->getMessage())` in the `unauthenticated()` method of the `App\Exceptions\Handler.php`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova It shows "Unauthenticated."

Comment: How did you create the user? Are you sure the password is hashed (both in creation and authentication)?

Comment: Why you did not use `php artisan make:auth`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova The user is correct, cause it'd show an error message when not using correct info.

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz For this project, we arent using the laravel 5 Auth stuff, just the middleware. In another project (laravel 5.3) a login works, but it doesnt want to work in my current project and I have no clue why.

Comment: Can you post your `guards` array from `config/auth.php` as well?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova added.

Comment: In `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` there is a method `authenticate`, can you `dd($guards)` before the first `if`?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Just shows empty array, two square brackets, nothing in it.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Cant talk due to not enough rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel models default to `id` as a column name in `Models`. If you use anything different that `id`, you should set a `protected` property `$primaryKey` with the name of your table's primary key. Eg:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'Leerling_ID';
```

Documentation: [Eloquent: #Primary Keys](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment: Thanks so much for the amazing help.